# MVC Custom authentication?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I write a small mvc application which uses custom authentication. All actions in the application use the following annotation except login action of Account controller: `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "User")]`
That means every page will be redirected to login page for authentication. The app works fine except a small error. In the application properties page I set the **start action** to **current page**. When the application starts, I expect the application will redirect to login page but it returns the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: What's about your RouteConfig.cs? Add Default Route
routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
           url:   {controller}/{action}/{id}"
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Ok. The problem is that I remove HomeController but I don't modify the RouteConfig.cs for the default route. Now It is fixed. Thanks  Md. Asaduzzaman.

Comment: Then I am adding this as a comment and mark it as a correct answer. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Check your route config file

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = 
            UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```